# Timer in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins, timer

I searched a lot in google and didn't find a reliable one. That's why I asked this question.

I am dynamically creating a `iframe` and the iframe in a `div`.

I need to show and start the `TIMER` count , starts from **[00:00:00]** which is in the format of **[hh:mm:ss]** , after my `JSP` is fully loaded.

So I have used the following `plugin` http://tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/

But It doesn't work for me in **IE** and works in **chrome** and **firefox**.. Only I got the **alert** message . Other than nothing happend.My JSP code is ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/assets/countup/jquery.countup.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert("DOM loaded");
        $('#countdown').countup();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Timer is :</h2>

    <p id="countdown"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't why this is not working for me.

**My need :**

- I need to show and start the `TIMER` count , starts from **[00:00:00]** which is in the format of **[hh:mm:ss]** , after DOM is fully loaded in IE in the specified format.
- Or suggest me any other things to make this scenario works.

Hope our stack users will help me.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/4LM9g/ are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Anton But it not works in IE

Comment: What version of IE are you using, because it's working on IE9

Comment: @Anton using IE8 . Also it does not show the image.

Comment: I don't think the plugin supports IE8

Comment: Anton is right, even their demo is not working in IE8... what a piece of crap from MS :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally , I found the **solution** for my requirement by my own code,

```
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;

$(function() {
    setInterval(counter, 1000);

});

function counter() {


    var hh = 0;
    var mm = 0;
    var ss = 0;

    seconds = seconds + 1;
    ss = seconds + 1;
    if (seconds == 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = minutes + 1;
        mm = minutes + 1;
        if (minutes == 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours = hours + 1;
            hh = hours + 1;
        }
    }

    if (seconds < 10) {
        ss = "0" + seconds;
    }else{
        ss = seconds;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        mm = "0" + minutes;
    }else{
        mm = minutes;
    }
    if (hours < 10) {
        hh = "0" + hours;
    }else{
        hh = hours;
    }

    $('#displayTime').html("[ " +hh + " : " + mm + " : " + ss+" ]");

}
```